# How exactly do I create a sed script and use it to edit a file?

Tags: bash, command-line, sed

I know how to edit a file using sed one step at a time, but how would I create an actual sed script and then use it on the file to do the same things that the individual sed commands would do? For example these 3 sed commands:

> sed -i '4i\ ' baconFile
>
> sed -i 's/,/\t\t/' baconFile
>
> sed -i 's/,/ /' baconFile

Answer (score 32):

#### Putting commands in a file

Put these lines in a script file named `script.sed`.

```
4i\ 
s/,/\t\t/
s/,/ /
```

Then run it like this:

```
$ sed -i -f script.sed baconFile
```

#### Making a standalone sed script

if you want it to be a single executable then do this:

```
#/bin/bash

sed -i '
4i\ 
s/,/\t\t/
s/,/ /
' "$@"
```

Put the above lines into a file called `script.bash`, make it executable (`chmod +x script.bash`, and run it like this:

```
$ script.bash baconFile
```

#### Creating the script file

You can use this method to make the file I mentioned above.

```
$ cat > script.bash <<EOF
#!/bin/bash

4i\ 
s/,/\t\t/
s/,/ /
EOF
```

This will make the script file. You can confirm using this command:

```
$ cat script.bash
#!/bin/bash

4i\ 
s/,/\t\t/
s/,/ /
```

Comment: Sorry, still a bit confused as to how to actually create a sed file, say sed1, then put the commands inside of it, then use it on a file, say baconFile. Sorry.

Comment: It is possible to use the shebang line `#!/usr/bin/sed -f -` to write a sed script as a callable script. EDIT: Actually that seems to depend on the implementation of sed. GNU sed does not appear to support `-f -`, and that is what most people are probably using these days. Actually, BSD sed doesn't support this either, but AIX sed does. Go figure!

Comment: @GregHewgill - that's what I thought, I took that last statement out, thanks!

Comment: @John - see my example above, I made a file called script.bash, put the contents as I mentioned into it, make it executable, and run it like this, `script.bash baconFile`.

Comment: I am still a bit confused as to how the sed1 script is made. What is this doing? #/bin/bash   Also I have tried using these commands: #/bin/bash

sed -i '
4i\ 
s/,/\t\t/
s/,/ /
' "$@"    but I get error message: sed: no input files

Comment: @John - that is called a shebang line. That makes this file a script, and tells the shell what interpreter to use, in this case we're using Bash.

Comment: Just to clarify, I do know how to use a created sed script file on a file, I just do not know exactly how to create the sed script and put the commands in it =/ Sorry guys.

Comment: @John - Sorry I thought you might be asking that but didn't want to offend you. You can use a editor such as `nano` to create this file. Also I updated my answer showing how you can make the file using the `cat` command.

Comment: Alright thanks! How would I made a sed script called sed1 though? I see yours is called script.bash. Is the .bash extension required?

Comment: @John - the extensions in Linux are irrelevant, they're just so that operators of the computer know what the file is 8-). To make it `sed1`, change this line like so: `cat > sed1 <<EOF`. Everything else should stay the same.

Answer (score 7):

```
sed -i '4i\ 

s/,/\t\t/

s/,/ /' baconFile
```

sed works like most interpreters, multiple commands can be on separate lines or delimited by `;`. if you don't have `GNU sed` your first line may cause an error.

---

To create a sed script, you just give the absolute path to your sed interpreter in your shebang. and make sure the file is executable.

```
#!/bin/sed -f
s/foo/bar/

chmod u+x foo
./foo <<<foo
bar
```

or the script could be called along with the sed command.
`sed -i -f foo file`

Comment: I meant how would I make a script of the commands so I would not have to type out all of the commands every time I wanted to do it to a file?

Comment: +1 For using the right shebang... (Why would you start bash just to start sed???)

Answer (score 4):

You need the `-f` option `sed -f sed-script`

Answer (score 3):

You can write a bash or korn shell script to do this. If you want to make it dynamic, you can make it so it takes in a file name as a parameter and you can run these sed commands on any file you want.

Create a new file, say `updatefile.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
#$1 is the first parameter being passed when calling the script. The variable filename will be used to refer to this.
filename=$1

sed '4i\ ' filename
sed 's/,/\t\t/' filename
sed 's/,/ /' filename
```

You can then run `updatefile.sh baconFile` which will run all three sed commands for the file `baconFile`.

Also, the `g` option in sed will update all occurrences of the variable in the file. For example:

```
sed 's/,/ /g' filename
```